# Vlookup from a folder

Tags: excel, vlookup, powerquery

I need the help with the following problem statement -

I receive daily price for particular products as a csv file. Now I need to track the price of these products on a time-series basis.

I have all the price files in a folder. Need to come up with a solution so that whenever a new file is added to the folder - the master price sheet automatically gets updated with a new column for that date with the prices.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does using Google Sheets ok with you or you have to use Excel?

Comment: So you want a macro that periodically checks for new files (How are you tracking that - by Filename?  Create date?), imports it, and then stores the file details in a hidden sheet to compare against next time it checks for a new file?